# Python: simplest way to join strings inserting a string between them?

Tags: python, string

```
strs = ['x=1', 'b=4', 'x=4']
```

I want to get:

```
str = 'x=1 AND b=4 AND x=4'
```

What is a simplest way to do that in Python?

P.S. too stupid question
Found:

```
' AND '.join( strs )
```

Comment: You shouldn't call your variable `str` (not even for a quick example), there is a builtin `str`

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> strs = ['x=1', 'b=4', 'x=4']
>>> print ' AND '.join(strs)
x=1 AND b=4 AND x=4
```

Answer (score 2):

You answered you own question, [`join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) is the way to do this.

```
' '.join(strs)
```

Will put a space between each item in strs. And the following:

```
' AND '.join(strs)
```

Will put ' AND ' between each item.